# Error al entrenar el algoritmo GradientBoostingRegressor de SKlearn

Tags: python, algoritmos, scikit-learn, google-colab

```
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
    
    param_test1 = {'n_estimators':range(20,501,20)}
    estimator = GradientBoostingRegressor(learning_rate=0.1, 
                                           min_samples_split=500,
                                           min_samples_leaf=50,
                                           max_depth=8,
                                           max_features='sqrt',
                                           subsample=0.8,
                                           random_state=10)
    gsearch1 = GridSearchCV(estimator, 
                            param_grid = param_test1, 
                            scoring='r2', 
                            cv=5,return_train_score= True)-
    
    gsearch1.fit(X_train, y_train)`>
```

me aparece el siguiente error

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-458-db157d37b4a0> in <module>()
----> 1 gsearch1.fit(X_train, y_train)

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/ensemble/_gb.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight, monitor)
    407         # trees use different types for X and y, checking them separately.
    408 
--> 409         X, y = self._validate_data(X, y, accept_sparse=['csr', 'csc', 'coo'],
    410                                    dtype=DTYPE, multi_output=True)
    411         n_samples, self.n_features_ = X.shape

AttributeError: 'GradientBoostingRegressor' object has no attribute '_validate_data'
```